# Multiple Listviews using same Adapter class and same CallBack Interface to Activity

Tags: android, listview, interface, callback, adapter

I have two custom ListViews each with their own adapter, but of the same class.  So each has the same CallBack Interface to the activity.

I am struggling with how the Activity can distinguish which ListView is running the CallBack.  A listener sends the selected value back to the Activity.  However, each ListView has similar select-able values (i.e. 1,2,3,4).  So the selected value alone isn't enough to distinguish between which ListView the selection originated.

Answer (score 0):

Callback listener should not be implemented by the same activity class.
You can implement listeners for the two listViews on their own.

For example:

```
listView1.setOnItemClickListener(listener1);
listView2.setOnItemClickListener(listener2);
```

Answer (score 0):

**To get more readability use anonymous interface like this:**

```
lstView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int pos, long arg3) {

                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it by set 2 list is global variables. And check in your callback like:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int pos, long arg3) {
    if(arg0 == mListView1){// listview1 item click}
    else if(arg0 == mListView2){// listview2 item click}
}
```

Hope this help.